# kinect for windows V2.0 Developer Preview, camera working, depth sensor not working

Tags: windows, kinect, kinect-sdk

I installed KinectSDK-v2.0-DevPreview1311 in my Windows 8.1 Operating System. While running KinectService.exe the status  is

```
    ConnectionManager - DeviceNotification
    VVTechs SwitchVersion failed 0x80070057
    ConnectionManager - DeviceNotification
    ConnectionManager::_OnDeviceStatus - Connected
```

As a result camera is detected but depth sensor is not detected.

My Hardware specifications are Core i3 Ideapad, 4GB  RAM

OS: windows 8.1

Update:
I updated my SDK to latest version (1403)

```
    ConnectionManager - DeviceNotification
    Ctrl+C to exit.

    ConnectionManager::_OnAcquireColor status failed with 0x000003e3
    ConnectionManager::_OnAcquireColor status failed with 0x000003e3
    ConnectionManager::_OnAcquireColor status failed with 0x000003e3
    ConnectionManager::_OnAcquireColor status failed with 0x000003e3
    ConnectionManager::_OnAcquireColor status failed with 0x000003e3
    VVTechs SwitchVersion failed 0x80070057
    TerminateNuiService(1)
    ConnectionManager - DeviceNotification
    ConnectionManager::_OnDeviceStatus - Connected
```

Does any body know about the problem ?

Comment: I get the "VVTechs SwitchVersion failed 0x80070057" error even when the kinect is not connected at all.

Comment: Hey, are you using VM Ware by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

Installing the most up to date SDK (DevPreview 1403) directly, led to the same problem on my Windows 8.1 OS. You did not mention if you have run the KinectFirmwareUpdate which seems to be important in order to use the Kinect Sensor properly.

What I have done in order to solve it:

1. Remove the currently installed SDK
2. Install the old SDK 1311
3. Run KinectFirmwareUpdate App
4. Remove old SDK 1311
5. Install SDK 1403
6. Run KinectFirmwareUpdate App

After applying the steps listed above, the problem did not occur anymore executing KinectService.

Hopefully it will help you, too.

Comment: Hey, I tried this. It didn't work for me. Question, are you using VM Ware or are you Boot Camping or using a Windows machine?

Comment: Hi, no I did not use any VM Ware or Boot Camp Software. On my machine I have installed Windows 8 since it is a requirement to run Kinect SDK properly.

Comment: Where can one find old Kinect SDK with KinectFirmwareUpdate.exe?

Comment: wonder where one can find older Kinect 2.x (can only find 1410, not the 1406 that had KinectFirmwareUpdate.exe - the new one seems to have firmware updating embedded in KinectService which seems to not do the job or not sure how to force update)

Comment: "KinectFirmwareUpdate.exe is a standalone tool in Kinect SDK <= v2.0_1406. It has this string:

   -critical        Use with extreme caution and use only if explicitly
                    directed! This option will update the sensor's
                    boot critical files."

https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2/issues/460?fbclid=IwAR0C-S8fqrgAfERynRhu0DplPOkFAYusEdJC2OatdynzcVHvZcpWnM4g5v4#issuecomment-156077738

Comment: related: https://elbruno.com/2013/11/29/kinectone-getting-started-with-the-new-kinectone-sensor-k4w/

Comment: is there any archive of older versions for Kinect v2 SDK?